# Finding f(0) when putting x as zero results in a zero denominator

Tags: calculus

I was given this problem:

> The function $f$ is continuous on the open interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.
>
> If $f(x)=\frac{\cos x-1}{x\sin x}$ for $x\neq 0$, what is the value of $f(0)$?

When you plug in zero, you get $\frac00$. It can't be using L'Hopital's rule because it is not asking for a derivative. It must be that the function must be rearranged in some way - but how? Or am I just thinking along the wrong lines completely?

Comment: You can use l’Hopital’s rule for a limit

Comment: Oh, so I set a limit as x approaches zero and then solve?

Comment: Use Taylor expansions http://www.h-k.fr/publications/data/adc.ps__annexes.maths.pdf

Comment: Yes, @burt; you may need to apply the rule twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use L'Hôpital's rule here. That's exactly what it's for! Differentiating numerator and denominator and setting $x=0$ gives you $\frac00$, but don't be discouraged $-$ just differentiate them again and you will get non-zero values. (This is just what Chinnapparaj R's answer does, but without any explanation.)

Alternatively, you can use the series expansions $\cos x=1-\frac12x^2+O(x^4)$ and $\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)$ to get the same answer.

Comment: What is series expansions?

Comment: @burt: I meant the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos(x)+1$ and use that $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$
It is
$$\frac{\cos^2(x)-1}{(\cos(x)+1)x\sin(x)}=\frac{-\sin^2(x)}{(\cos(x)+1)x\sin(x)}=-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{1}{\cos(x)+1}$$

Comment: This is not using L'Hopital's rule, correct. Instead it is algebraically manipulating the problem? What is the advantage of using this method? Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin x}{x \cos x+\sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\cos x}{-x \sin x+2 \cos x}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ so define $f(x)=-1/2$ at $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x -1}{x\sin x} = \lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{\sin x}{x(1+\cos x)}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Then, you must to define $f(0)=-1/2$, since $f$ is continuous in $0$.